# Is it possible to embed all scripts and CSS into the rendered page in Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Using a custom Next.js server, I have a particular page that's generated specifically to be embedded into another page. However, I'm finding that certain browsers (Safari and Brave) will be overzealous in their blocking and block scripts or stylesheets from this server's domain. In theory, I feel that it'd be simpler to serve this single page with all of its resources embedded into the page, requiring no further requests. However, I'm not sure how to accomplish this in Next.js.

How would I render a page in Next.js and render all of its scripts and stylesheets directly within the HTML? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

1. create a top-level layout component just for that page
2. If it will be the only page with this special layout, you may need to put some logic in your nextjs `_app.js` file to inspect the route and then wrap the page component with your special layout only under certain circumstances
3. use `import Head from 'next/head'` in the layout file, and then add
   a `<Head>...</Head>` jsx component to your layout, within
   which
   you can populate typical head tags like link, meta and script tags.
   Your scripts can be referenced here.